# How to Get Data from remote Webservice using jquery

Tags: html, web-services, jquery

I have problem in binding data to a control in html page,here we have a web service in remote location as we are binding the data to a control(dropdown) in html the data is not binding the code for fine for localhost but for the remote url.here i'm placing code below can any one tell me any modifications or any code to be added to it.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<select id="CbxArea" style="width: 200px">
    <option>Select Area</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //debugger;
        var requestUrl = 'http://192.168.3.252:8081/HaraveerWCF/ExcelDataService.asmx/GetAreaNames';
        var ddlArea = $("#CbxArea");
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.3.252:8081/HaraveerWCF/ExcelDataService.asmx/GetAreaNames",
            //url: "ExcelDataService.asmx/GetAreaNames",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; encoding=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    ddlArea.append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].AreaName).html(data.d[i].AreaName));
                };
                alert(data.d.AreaName);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $('#status').innerHTML = "Unavailable";
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i have tried your reuqesturl in browser but its not opening...

Comment: I did a post request using firefox poster tool(extension) I did not receive any response from the url. May be you can recheck if the URL is correct and can do what JakeGould suggested to get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: i have checked the url in other machines it worked fine,but data is not binding to the combobox.The url is public url.